# Font-family no funciona en mi pagina

Tags: html, css

He decidido usar la fuente de google **"Raleway"** con lo cual he añadido esto a mi código:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
```

Y esto en mi css:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Pero no funciona. Tampoco funciona con las fuentes convencionales que no son de google.

He probado de poner `!important` y sin, pero no funciona de ninguna manera (lo he puesto en el `body` y `html` porque quiero esa fuente en toda la página).

Comment: Funciona: [demo](http://jsbin.com/rosequcajo/1/edit?html,css,output)... donde tienes tu stylesheet?

Comment: ¿Esas pruebas las haces en local o la web está en internet?

Comment: He eliminado la respuesta ya que como me ha apuntado @aldanux no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Como te había indicado en un comentario puede parecer una pregunta tonta pero, ¿has linkeado el css con el html?

Comment: De momento lo estoy haciendo en local pero en la web tampoco funciona

Comment: Primeramente, comprueba que la hoja de estilos esté enlazada en el html.
Si está bien, pero sigue sin verse, tal vez al escribir haya algún símbolo extraño oculto entre las letras. En ocasiones el sublime-text me lo ha hecho, y al copiar el texto en otro lugar me mostraba algo que no se veía.

Comment: @PavloB. - no importa si lo tienes local o en la web... lo importante es que esté correctamente el link a tu `css/stylesheet`... por ejemplo:  `<link href="./css/tufichero.css"...`

Comment: @aldanux Dices que no importa si es o no en local pero hay veces que si importa, podía haber alguna configuración en su hosting o su ordenador que provocara el fallo, algún problema con `https`, muchas cosas, no puedes decir que da igual así sin más

Comment: @blonfu - si esta mal la ruta...está mal.... no importa si es local o no

Comment: @aldanux eso si. Igual te he entendido mal ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona bien como te han dicho los compañeros. Sólo haz referencia a tu hoja de estilos poniendo:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tu-ruta-a/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

O sólo poniendo esa parte directamente, aunque no es lo recomendable:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html, body {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Parece ser que el error de que no te vaya el CSS es que no lo tienes bien linkeado a tu html. Para ello, en tu html tendrás que usar lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
```

en `href` tendrás que indicar la ruta de tu archivo `CSS` tomando como referencia tu archivo `html`.

Puedes usar rutas absolutas o rutas relativas, sin embargo, te recomiendo que no uses rutas absolutas (ejemplo: `C://ruta/ruta/estilos.css`) y uses rutas relativas ya que si mueves tu proyecto a otro ordenador posiblemente las rutas ya no funcionarán.

Usando rutas relativas y tomando como referencia tu archivo html imaginate la siguiente estructura:

```
|
|---css
|      |
|      |--- estilos.css
|
|------html
```

Tendrías que usar `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">`.

En cambio para esta otra ruta:

```
|---css
|      |
|      |--- estilos.css
|
|---vistashtml
       |
       |--- pagina.html
```

Tendrías que usar `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">`.

Con los dos puntos `../` se indica que has subido al directorio padre del directorio en el que te encuentras.

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

puede sonar trivial mi respuesta pero en ocasiones en lugar de

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
```

va

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css"/>
```